# Getting started with my first project with connectivity between devices

Tags: ionic-framework, server, send, connectivity

I've been developing some pretty basic applications using the Ionic-framework.

I've now started a project where I want two devices to communicate, or at least be able to send and receive data.

I've tried googling for keywords such as connectivity and other tutorials, I've also looked through the Ionic framework documentation. I haven't found any place to start from and didn't know where else to turn but here to ask where I could find resources to get started with developing my first application which could be able to recieve and send data to other app-users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use **push notification** so that you can communicate with device i hope it will help http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) will be the best solution in your case.

Let's imagine we're doing a Chat.

User A sends a message (just register it in Firebase), that message triggers a push notification that's received by User B.

User B opens the app and updates the data (just update his local data froma from Firebase).

That's all :)

Just take a look, but you can use Firebase for every kind of apps that needs to store data.